# Counting frequencies of several groups at the same time

Tags: r

I am tracking the handling of many research fields in peer-reviewed literature, and have processed almost 1500 papers. In my data file I have columns for 25 topics, annotated in the data file with 1 (presence) and 0 (absence). The data file schematically looks like this:

```
TITLE AUTHORS JOURNAL YEAR ... TOPIC1 TOPIC2 TOPIC3 TOPIC4 ... TOPIC25
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2002          1      0      0      1           0
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2012          0      0      0      0           1
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2002          0      0      1      1           0
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2015          1      0      0      0           0
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2015          0      0      0      0           0
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2013          0      0      1      1           1
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2012          1      0      0      0           0
'xxx'  'yyy'    'zzz' 2012          0      0      1      0           1
```

I need to count the frequencies of various topics in the papers and end up with a data frame looking like this:

```
TOPIC  count
TOPIC1    7
TOPICS2  19
.
.
TOPIC25  15
```

I've been googling, reading about and trying a few different things, but nothing have worked so far, thus no code posted.

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does the expected output reflect the input example?.  Perhaps `lapply(df1[grep("^TOPIC\\d+", names(df1))], sum)`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but the the names are not really TOPICS1:TOPIC25, but they all have different names -> POPABU, POPTR, POPSTAT, HARV, CC, HAB,POLL, ZOO, PHYS, TEK etc.

Comment: If that is the case you should have showed that in the example.  How do we know that you have `POPABU`, `POPTR` etc in the data if you don't specify it.  So, instead of the `grep`, if you know the column index, you can do `lapply(df1[5:ncol(df1)], sum)`

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise, I am new to this webpage and I am learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the columns of interest, get the `sum` and `stack` it to create a two column 'data.frame'.

```
res <- setNames(stack(lapply(df1[grep("^TOPIC\\d+", names(df1))],
          sum))[2:1], c("TOPIC", "count"))
head(res,2)
#   TOPIC count
#1 TOPIC1     7
#2 TOPIC2     19
```

If the column names doesn't have any pattern, use the column index to subset the columns i.e. suppose if `POPABU` is the 5th column and `POPGEN` is the last column,

```
res <- setNames(stack(lapply(df1[5:ncol(df1)],
          sum))[2:1], c("TOPIC", "count"))
```

Comment: How does this work when the real topic names in the data file are as such: POPABU, POPTR, POPSTAT, HARV, CC, HAB,POLL, ZOO, PHYS, TEK, HWC, DIS, ANA, POPGEN, etc.?